# Can a single folder can be configured for both anonymous FTP and HTTP in IIS 7.0

Tags: ftp, windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7

I am using Windows server 2008 R2 VPS(with IIS 7) as my web server for hosting websites, ftp etc.

Can I configure a anonymous ftp account to work with both ftp and http? (FTP account with security can be made accessible by both ftp and http) .I want users to access it using both ftp or http without authentication(anonymous). I have some files which I place in both http and ftp, so users can download it by using http or ftp. but it eats double space in web server as I copy files to both folders. So I wanted to know  is it possible to configure a folder as both anonymous ftp and http.

Comment: Of course it can.  Just configure IIS to use the same folder.

Comment: @Ramhound I think we can create only one anonymous FTP for one IP address. Is that true? Also when creating FTP anonynous FTP account i should give folder which is inside the root of the domain( so that it can be accessed from both ftp and http?   (Now i am using plesk which creates "anon_ftp" folder in the root of IP.) In my case about 3 websites are their with same IP.